# Hyperlink C1Flexgrid Column Data in silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, componentone, c1flexgrid

I am using Component one FlexGrid in my silverlight Application and it is autogenerating columns in the grid. I want to make one of the column's data behave as a clickable hyperlink. Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to add hyperlink cell in C1FlexGrid.
One should extend **CellFactory** Class and inside the class 
override method CreateCellContent(C1FlexGrid grid, Border bdr, CellRange range)
and write something like this:

```
public override void CreateCellContent(C1FlexGrid grid, Border bdr, CellRange range)
    {
      //Ofcourse One should figure out first the col in which they want to       
      //add the cell
       var width = GetWidthForHyperlinkControl((string)grid[range.Row, range.Column]);
       var cell = new HyperlinkControl
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                Width = width,
                Height = 16,
                NavigateUri = null,
                IsTabStop = false,
                Content = (string)grid[range.Row, range.Column]
            };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample projects for ComponentOne FlexGrid include a Hyperlink sample.  Should be part of your installed items.

If not, you can also access it via the [ComponentOne website](http://our.componentone.com/samples/winforms-hyperlink/).

Essentially, you set up a style for the hyperlink cells/columns and apply it.  You can use `OwnerDrawCell` events to do it, as the example shows.